# InDesign Target XML Structure element by partial name

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

In my Structure pane there are some elements that their partial name is identical, eg. image01, image03, image03 etc.

I want to know if there is a way to access them via scripting using the itemByName() method, but by providing a partial name, like in CSS i can use

```
h1[rel*="external"]
```

Is there a similar way to do this in:

```
var items2 = items.xmlElements.itemByName("image");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the code below. You can test against the `markupTag.name` properties with a regular expression. The regex is equivalent to something like `/^image/` in your example (find `image` at the beginning of a string).

```
function itemsWithPartialName(item, partialName) {
   var elems = item.xmlElements;
   var result = [];

   for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
      var elem = elems[i];
      var elemName = elem.markupTag.name;

      var regex = new RegExp("^" + partialName);
      if (regex.test(elemName)) {
         result.push(elem);
      }
   }

   return result;
}

itemsWithPartialName(/* some xml item */, 'image');
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because markupTag.name returns undefined.

    function itemsWithPartialName(partialName) {
    var items = app.activeDocument.xmlElements.everyItem();
    var sub_items = items.xmlElements.everyItem();
    var count_images = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<items.xmlElements.count(); i++) {
    var elemName = items.xmlElements[i].markupTag.name;
    //alert(elemName);
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + partialName);
    if (regex.test(elemName)) {
    count_images++;
    }
    }
    return count_images;
    }

Comment: Try `var sub_items = items.everyItem().xmlElements;` (untested). This assumes the root element has sub elements... Can you post an example of your xml structure and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: My structure is like that:

newspaper
    >>cars_pa
    >>cars
    >>apartments_pa
    >>apartments
    >>image01
    >>image02
    >>image03
    >>image04
    >>image05
    >>image06
    >>image07....

(why can't I have a hard-return? what am I typing wrong?)

Newspaper is the root element and everything else is lvl-1 child

Comment: See Dirk's answer which also gives a good solution with xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XPath:

```js
var rootXE = app.activeDocument.xmlElements.item(0);
var tagXEs = rootXE.evaluateXPathExpression("//*[starts-with(local-name(),'image')]");
```